# How to slice dict values to different list

Tags: python, regex, slice, pycrypto, ccxt

```
import ccxt
import time
import re

exchanges = {'mercado', 'bitfinex', 'quadrigacx','binance'}

limit = 10

def get_order_book(key,symbol):
    exchange = eval('ccxt.' + key + '()' )
    orderbook = exchange.fetch_order_book(symbol,limit)
    print (list(orderbook.keys()))

    bid = orderbook['bids']
    print (bid)

get_order_book('bitfinex', 'BTC/USD')

>>['bids', 'asks', 'timestamp', 'datetime', 'nonce']
[[6603.6, 0.02189108], [6603.1, 0.15613008], [6602.7, 1.508], [6602.0, 0.05], [6601.3, 1.0], [6601.0, 0.00499], [6600.5, 0.63660326], [6600.3, 1.5094], [6600.0, 9.0], [6598.1, 0.18676835]]
```

The function `bids` returns a list with two values for each index, first is `price`, second is `amount`.

Its possible to slice this list into two lists, one with `price` and another with `amount`?

or put this into a nested dict key, for me to use later?

Instead of returning a list it will assign the two values of each index on the list to a nested dict

Like `new_orderbook['bids']['price']` for the first number
And `new_orderbook['bids']['amount']` for the second number

Comment: `prices, amounts = zip(*pairs)`.

Answer (score 0):

@ekhumoro is correct.

You can unzip these pairs by passing [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) the iterator it contains preceded by the `*` operator.

```
>>> bid
[[4030.1, 0.17328499], [4030.0, 0.73859736], [4029.7, 1.921567], [4027.9, 0.31081552], [4027.3, 0.05842284], [4027.2, 1.26534116], [4027.0, 0.19425388], [4026.9, 0.04], [4026.7, 0.0133796], [4026.3, 0.93483375]]
>>> prices, amounts = zip(*bid)
>>> list(prices)
[4030.1, 4030.0, 4029.7, 4027.9, 4027.3, 4027.2, 4027.0, 4026.9, 4026.7, 4026.3]
>>> list(amounts)
[0.17328499, 0.73859736, 1.921567, 0.31081552, 0.05842284, 1.26534116, 0.19425388, 0.04, 0.0133796, 0.93483375]
```